# iOS earphones touches processing

Tags: ios, iphone

I want add functionality to the app for work with earphones, and cannot found any information about button processing from earphones.

Is it possible to recognize touch on it? (but +/Center button/-)

[There](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-control-your-iphone-ipod-with-apple-earphones-with-remote-and-mic.805237/) describe how it works in standard app, and I want to add similar navigation to my app. Have any idea?

Comment: Look at: `UIEventTypeRemoteControl` maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Larme!

I found good explanation about this theme:

[iOS - UIEventTypeRemoteControl events not received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083940/ios-uieventtyperemotecontrol-events-not-received)

http://www.widecodes.com/0SmVqgjPWP/how-can-i-send-uieventtyperemotecontrol-events.html